# Python generic exception bad practice concept

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have the below script:

```
import jtp_aux as aux


def logger_path(path_logger):
    return aux.init_logger(path_logger)


def generic_function(a, b):
    return a/b


def main():
    logger = logger_path(r'log_scratch.log')
    try:
        print(generic_function(2, 'l'))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e, exc_info=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would need to catch any error thrown by the code and save into a file so I can analyse it later. However, I've been told that this generic exception catching is a bad practice and that the exceptions should be caught one by one, like this:

```
def main():
    logger = logger_path(r'log_scratch.log')
    try:
        print(generic_function(2, 'l'))
    except ValueError:
        # Do something
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        # Do something
```

However, I'm struggling to understand why is that considered best practice if an unexpected exception could make the program fail without saving the error into a log.
Any help with this will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: If you *know* the typical kind of error types you can and want to handle them differently you can do so without implementing your own pattern matching. If you handle everything the same then catching a plain Exception is fine.

Comment: its fine this way. you could even do `raise e`, causing no program behaviour change at all, apart from logging the exception. It's bad practice if you catch all errors even dough you only want to catch some. Say you're accessing a dict, but expect it to fail sometimes, so put it inside a try catch block. Then not checking for the specific exception could cause your program to ignore other, unrelated exceptions.

Comment: @Nearoo if I do raise e, will the program continue even if there is an error? Could you please help me with an example?

Comment: No, if you `raise e` again, then your program will stop. You're explicitly catching the exception to make your program *not stop*, even in the face of an error, right?

Comment: Well actually that would be the whole script so I might be better off by raising the exception then. Do I need to raise exception in each of the methods defined?

Comment: @banana_99 No, you put it into the `catch:` block, i.e. (on multiple lines) `catch Exception as e: logger.error(...); raise e`. This will look like there was no `try:catch:` block at all, but the exception will have been logged

Comment: @Nearoo sorry, I'm struggling to understand the concept, could you please post an answer of how my main would look like with that approach?

Comment: sure, posted one blow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine since you really intend to catch all exception. Catching all exceptions is considered bad practice only if you actually only want to catch few. For instance, in the code below, if you expect `get` to throw `KeyError` if `"Hello"` can't be found, you should only catch `KeyError`; if you catch everything, you might  miss a different exception (e.g. `ZeroDivisionError`):

```py
try:
    return myObj.get("Hello")

# bad: default value returned even though "Hello" might actually exist, but something else went wrong
except Exception as e:
    return "DefaultValue"

# good: default value only returned on KeyError; all other exceptions are raised normally
except KeyError as e:
    return "DefaultValue"
```

In your case, you could even re-raise the exception after logging it, making the program return to the regular exception handling:

```
try:
    x = 1 / 0
except Exception as e:
    print("Hello") # replace with logger.error(...) in your case
    raise e # exits the except block and raises the exception again
```

Output:

```
Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pygame_textinput/tests.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise e
  File "pygame_textinput/tests.py", line 5, in <module>
    x = 1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

If you do it like this, your code looks as though exceptions are raised normally from the outside, but you're also logging every exception you get.  An example case where this could be important is when you're calling a function that is define somewhere else, and is expected to raise an exception in certain conditions. You want this exception to be raise as expected, not catch and ignore it. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you need to catch any and all exceptions, `except Exception` is exactly what you want and is fine. It doesn't make sense to make it any more fine grained than that, if you're doing the same handling for any and all exceptions anyway.

In general though, you should be as detailed as possible when catching exceptions to make sure you're catching *expected* exceptions and let ***unexpected*** exceptions bubble up. E.g.:

```
a = 1
b = 0

try:
    c = a / B
except ...:
    ...
```

Here it makes a difference whether you catch only the expected `ZeroDivisionError` or *any error*. By limiting yourself to expecting `ZeroDivisionError`s, this code will **correctly fail** because of the `NameError` due to the typo'd variable name. If you caught any and all exceptions, you could be debugging this code for quite a while before you find the typo.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom …yes…?

Comment: @deceze thanks for the answer. Would it better to raise exceptions in the methods instead of doing a try except in the main?

Comment: @banana_99 [Mu?!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#"Unasking"_the_question)

Comment: I assume then this way is fine, thanks!